# Can I use tf.metrics.BinaryAccuracy in a multiclass classification problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, kaggle

I was making a model of classification of the Alzheimer dataset on Kaggle. with my own model which was not built with any transfer learning, It was giving an accuracy of max 60% + in validation which was not actually cool. So I searched some codes in kaggle, in order to know my caviets of my model

There I found that, one was using tf.kers.metrics.BinaryAccuracy in the metrics part to calculate the acc and it was giving a more than of 80% + acc. Is this valid?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oywl1.png)

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy` is used for binary labels. For more details go through [Tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/BinaryAccuracy).
Use `tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy` if labels are one-hot encoded.